# How can I supply a different email address to the user's PayPal email address through the PayPal checkout system

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a website where people buy digital downloads.  Up to now I've never collected an email address from the buyer at the point of checkout.  I just pass them through to PayPal, and trust that their PayPal account has the correct email address set up in it.

Naturally, a lot of people don't.  They have PayPal accounts tied to email addresses they've not used or checked in years.

Once they've made a payment, I process it via PDT and IPN.  The PDT is so that they can download their files instantly, as soon as PayPal redirects them back to my site.  Email address is irrelevant in this case.

A lot of people don't get redirected for one reason or another though (close their browser, network cuts out, etc), or they want to revisit the site to download their order at a later date.

For this I use IPN.  PayPal contacts my site, tells me about the transaction, and I send an order confirmation email to them.

But so often this goes to that unchecked/old email address that the user doesn't use any more.

In a nutshell then, I want to pass a current email address into the PayPal checkout process.

I have my own custom-coded cart on my website, and then use an encrypted "checkout with PayPal" button, that sends all of the data about what's in the cart to PayPal.

This sort of thing:

```
$cart['cmd']                = '_cart';
$cart['upload']             = 1;
$cart['custom']             = $_SESSION['cartGUID'];
$cart['business']           = WEBSITE_PAYPAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
$cart['currency_code']      = $currencyCode;
$cart['return']             = 'https://www.example.com/pdt';

$n = 0;
while ($a = $rs->fetch()) {
    $n++;

    $cart['amount_'.$n]         = $a['amount'];
    $cart['quantity_'.$n]       = $a['quantity'];
    $cart['shipping_'.$n]       = $a['postage'];
    $cart['item_number_'.$n]    = $a['id'];
    $cart['item_name_'.$n]      = $a['description'];
}

$encrypted = str_replace("\n", "", paypal_encrypt_via_exec($cart));

echo '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">';
echo     '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">';
echo     '<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="'.$encrypted.'">';

echo     '<p id="paypal-button">';
echo         '<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/buttons/checkout-logo-large.png" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it\'s fast, free and secure">
echo     '</p>';
echo '</form>';
```

You get the idea.

To pass an email through, I could append it onto the 'custom' field.

```
$cart['custom'] = $_SESSION['cartGUID'] . '|' . $email;
```

And then split it out when `'custom'` gets sent back to the site via IPN.  This seems very hacky though?

So instead I've tried this, which I think is the right way of doing it:

```
$cart['email']              = $userEmail;
$cart['address_override']   = 1;
```

But it doesn't seem to work, the email address that gets passed back via IPN is still their stock PayPal email address.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I also tried splitting `email` and `address_override` out as separate `<input type="hidden">` elements rather than making them part of the encrypted button, but that didn't appear to work either.

Comment: **address_override** is related to the "shipping address", no the email. And **email** is for auto-fill once the user is in PayPal. I believe the **custom** variable in your case is the way to go.

Comment: With experimentation the `email` address only seems to be useful for auto-filling for new/guest users, and irrelevant for anyone who already has a PayPal account. I think that's what you were saying, just clarifying for anyone else who finds this.